# Correcting mistakes in my first article!

Tags: publications

I published my first article in a journal, and for a final (typographic) revision, the editor sent me a mail with some remarks and said:

"Please insert the corrections directly onto the pdf proof using the annotation tools incorporated within Adobe Acrobat Reader. Using the cursor select the text for correction, right click and use the most appropriate single tool (i.e. 'Replace', 'Cross out' or 'Add note to text')"

But these last functions don't exist in adobe reader (pdf), do you think that he wants to say "adobe reader with paied version"? how can i do that ? do i have to pay or there is other solution ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

These tools should be available in the free (of charge) version of Adobe Reader, but you might have to "activate" them first. Quoted from [here](https://readingonscreen.wordpress.com/annotation/adobe-reader/):

> Open your PDF in Adobe Reader XI.
>
> Click the Comment button (top right), or select from the menu bar: View > Comment > Annotations. The Comment pane will appear on the right of the screen.
>
> Select an annotation tool listed under the Annotations heading, then click on the document where you want the annotation to be made. To draw lines or shapes, select the tools listed under the Drawing Markups heading.

Also make sure to download an up-to date version of Acrobat Reader.

Comment: @Monica thank you for your answer, i found these tools 'Cross out' or 'Add note to text' but there is no "replace" ? for me replace means to modify PDF and this seems to be not available !!  how can i replace a world by an other world for example ?

Comment: Select the text and use the replace tool. See here: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/mark-text-edits.html